# Select Value Closest to a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to run a function that queries a database table for the numeric value `mba_score` closest to a variable `$runscore`.  My function looks this way:

```
public function get_player($runscore)
{
   $per = $this
             ->db
         ->select('mba_id, abs($runscore - mba_score) as mba_rate', FALSE)
         ->order_by('mba_rate', 'ASC')
         ->get('nba_scores');
         ->limit(1);

        if ($per->num_rows > 0) {
            $p = $per->row_array();
            return $p['nba_id'];
        }
        return false;           
        }
```

The error I get is :

```
"Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$runscore' in 'field list'"
```

I've tried writing and re-writing this segment a number of times and haven't been able to get a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
select("mba_id, abs($runscore - mba_score) as mba_rate", FALSE)
```

With single quotes, the variable $runscore is not replaced with its value. If you want to use single quotes, you should use concatenation:

```
select('mba_id, abs('.$runscore.' - mba_score) as mba_rate', FALSE)
```

Comment: And remember to escape the input by `$this->db->escape($runscore)`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
->select("mba_id, abs($runscore - mba_score) as mba_rate", FALSE) //use doube quote
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 's in your variables

```
 ->select("mba_id, abs('".$runscore."' - mba_score) as mba_rate", FALSE)
         ->order_by('mba_rate', 'ASC')
         ->get('nba_scores');
         ->limit(1);
```